# Javascript Todolist category if else statement

Tags: javascript, oop

Hello I'm stuck on how to add category for my to do list.  When you click on Button of category need change class name.  I don't understand how to correctly write if/else statement when button is clicked.

plan how it need to work

1. Write task name
2. Choose Category
3. Add new task

May be somebody can help me out ore give some advice how to solve this problem!

Sorry for my english and if my question is to badly explained!

```js
var toDoList = function() {

  var addNewTask = function() {
      var input = document.getElementById("taks-input").value,
        itemTexts = input,
        colA = document.getElementById('task-col-a').children.length,
        colB = document.getElementById('task-col-b').children.length,
        taskBoks = document.createElement("div"),
        work = document.getElementById("work"),
        Category = "color-2",
        taskCount = 1;

      if (work.onclick === true) {
        var Category = "color";
      }
      taskBoks.className = "min-box";
      taskBoks.innerHTML = '<div class="col-3 chack" id="task_' + (taskCount++) + '"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></div><div class="col-8 task-text" id="taskContent"><p>' + itemTexts + '</p><span id="time-now"></span></div><div class="col-1 ' + (Category) + '"></div>'

      if (colB < colA) {
        var todolist = document.getElementById("task-col-b");
      } else {
        var todolist = document.getElementById("task-col-a");
      }
      //todolist.appendChild(taskBoks);
      todolist.insertBefore(taskBoks, todolist.childNodes[0]);
    },
    addButton = function() {
      var btn2 = document.getElementById("add-task-box");
      btn2.onclick = addNewTask;

    };

  addButton()
}
toDoList();
```

```css
p {
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 45px;
}
.chack {
  background-color: #4c4b62;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
}
.task-text {
  background-color: #55566e;
  height: 100%;
  width: 255px;
}
.color {
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fdcd63;
  float: right;
}
.color-2 {
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
}
.color-3 {
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
  float: right;
}
.task {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  float: left;
}
.chack,
.task-text {
  float: left;
}
.add-new-task {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 588px;
  background-color: rgb(85, 86, 110);
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.min-box {
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.center {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.fa-star {
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
#add-task-box {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: -7px;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgb(255, 198, 94);
  padding: 10px;
}
#taks-input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 350px;
  margin-top: -7px;
}
.category {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="add-new-task">
    <input type="text" id="taks-input">
    <button id="add-task-box">Add New Task box</button>
    <div class="category">
      <button class="catBtn" id="work">Work</button>
      <button class="catBtn" id="home">Home</button>
      <button class="catBtn" id="other">Other</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lg-task" id="bigTask"></div>
  <div class="task" id="task-col-a"></div>
  <div class="task" id="task-col-b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Vladimir, you need to be more specific and show only the parts of the code that are causing the problem or are affected by it. For instance, there seems to be no purpose of attaching your css. Here's more info on  [how to ask a good question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need to attach event to buttons, or store value based on click to some hidden element. Please see answer below based on event based approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to bind click event to your buttons and store that value in `Category`, so in you js add this

```
var toDoList = function() {

  // set to default
  var Category = "color-3";
  // attach event to buttons
  var catButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("catBtn");

  // assign value based on event
  var myCatEventFunc = function() {
    var attribute = this.getAttribute("id");
    if (attribute === 'work') {
      Category = 'color';
    } else if (attribute === 'home') {
      Category = 'color-2';
    }
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < catButtons.length; i++) {
    catButtons[i].addEventListener('click', myCatEventFunc, false);
  }
```

[Demo: Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/17v0svwa/)

and remove this code from `addNewTask` function

```
if (work.onclick === true) {
   var Category = "color";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit hard to understand what you are doing, what you are going for (a module of some kind?). You were not *that* far away from a working state.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Task</title>
<style>

p {
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 45px;
}
.chack {
  background-color: #4c4b62;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
}
.task-text {
  background-color: #55566e;
  height: 100%;
  width: 255px;
}
.color {
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fdcd63;
  float: right;
}
.color-2 {
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
}
.color-3 {
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
  float: right;
}
.task {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  float: left;
}
.chack,
.task-text {
  float: left;
}
.add-new-task {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 588px;
  background-color: rgb(85, 86, 110);
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.min-box {
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.center {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.fa-star {
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
#add-task-box {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: -7px;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgb(255, 198, 94);
  padding: 10px;
}
#taks-input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 350px;
  margin-top: -7px;
}
.category {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

</style>
<script>
var toDoList = function() {
  var addNewTask = function() {
      var input = document.getElementById("taks-input").value,
        itemTexts = input,
        colA = document.getElementById('task-col-a').children.length,
        colB = document.getElementById('task-col-b').children.length,
        taskBoks = document.createElement("div"),
        work = document.getElementById("work"),
        Category = "color-2",
        taskCount = 1;

      if (work.onclick === true) {
        Category = "color";
      }
      taskBoks.className = "min-box";
      taskBoks.innerHTML = '<div class="col-3 chack" id="task_' 
                             + (taskCount++) +
                           '"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></div><div class="col-8 task-text" id="taskContent"><p>' 
                             + itemTexts +
                           '</p><span id="time-now"></span></div><div class="col-1 '
                             + (Category) + '"></div>'

      if (colB < colA) {
        var todolist = document.getElementById("task-col-b");
      } else {
        var todolist = document.getElementById("task-col-a");
      }
      //todolist.appendChild(taskBoks);
      todolist.insertBefore(taskBoks, todolist.childNodes[0]);
    },
    // I don't know what to do with that?
    addButton = function() {
      var btn2 = document.getElementById("add-task-box");
      btn2.onclick = addNewTask();
    };
    // return the stuff you want to have public
    return {
             addNewTask:addNewTask
           };
}
var f;
// wait until all HTML is loaded and put the stuff from above into the variable `f`
// you can call it with f.someFunction() in your case f.addNewTask()
window.onload = function(){
  f = toDoList();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="add-new-task">
    <input type="text" id="taks-input">
    <button id="add-task-box" onclick="f.addNewTask()">Add New Task box</button>
    <div class="category">
      <button class="catBtn" id="work" >Work</button>
      <button class="catBtn" id="home">Home</button>
      <button class="catBtn" id="other">Other</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lg-task" id="bigTask"></div>
  <div class="task" id="task-col-a"></div>
  <div class="task" id="task-col-b"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html
```

I hope you understood what I did?